# Determine size of ag-grid in rows before populating

Tags: resize, rows, ag-grid

How can I determine the number of rows that can be displayed in an ag-grid grid, prior to filling the data set?

The grid API's `getDisplayedRowCount()` returns 0 since there are no rows yet.

I would also need to track this information on grid resizes.